# Retrieve something from different Azure subscriptions at the same time

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to run a PowerShell Cmdlet against multiple Azure subscriptions, that's why I've thought about running it within a foreach loop but it did not work:

```
$Subscriptions = (Get-AzureRmSubscription).SubscriptionId
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions)
{
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $sub
    Do the task Cmdlet
}
```

Actually what it does is to run the task against the last subscription it was able to select.
Any better ways to workaround this?

Unfortunately the result cannot be exported to a csv file or a variable because it is displayed under the subscription info, as shown in the following figure.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Set-AzureRmContext` cmdlet to set the subscription:

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription | ForEach-Object {
  $_ | Set-AzureRmContext
  # do your task
 }
```

Comment: But the results are displayed under the subscriptions. Is there a method to display only the result in a formatted list?

Comment: Please explain that further and add a sample output you retrieve and what you expect.

Comment: Please edit your anser (not posting it as a comment) and also show the desired output

Comment: Done, recheck please

Comment: pipe the result of the `Set-AzureRmContet` to `Out-Null`: 
`$_ | Set-AzureRmContext | Out-Null`

Comment: Thanks that works too, but the results only indicates the the users without their indicating in which subscription they are. How can I workaround that?

Comment: Please start a new question.